# Missing dependency when run mvn -o clean package after mvn dependency:go-offline in creating docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile

I am using maven:3.8.2-adoptopenjdk-15 image to build an image for my application.

```
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.8.2-adoptopenjdk-15 AS Build

COPY src /home/app/src

COPY pom.xml /home/app

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml dependency:go-offline

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml -o clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk15

COPY --from=Build /home/app/target/mango-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/mango.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/mango.jar"]
```

This is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fruits</groupId>
    <artifactId>mango</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mango</name>
    <description>Mango is delicious</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.14.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is log:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11:50 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-03T12:24:13Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Removing intermediate container 29451ca8eee0
---> 4d3a862e9b50
Step 5/9 : RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml -o clean package
---> Running in d3e4eb87c567
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.fruits:mango >--------------------------
[INFO] Building mango 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.8 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.447 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-03T12:24:17Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mango: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.fruits:mango:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final, org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.4, org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.8, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.8, net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7, net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml -o clean package' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The first `BUILD SUCCESS` is for `RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml dependency:go-offline` (log for download dependencies so long so I don't copy that)

But when I build the image, in "mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml -o clean package" step, it shows an error that I missing some dependency which not included in my pom.xml. I test these maven commands on the computer and it working properly, the problem just happen when I build an image from the above Dockerfile.

Anyone can give me a clue, thanks.

Comment: A good reason why building inside a container? And building from outside and just copying the final result into the container?

Comment: Maven saves it's dependencies in an .m2 folder `C:\Users\<User_Name>\.m2` rename the folder temporarily or delete it and try the process again on your machine (**not** in the container) to check if the difference is caused by a caching problem

Comment: @khmarbaise yeah, but I want to test multi-stage in Dockerfile and automating the process completely. I am curious that why this problem happens when run in docker too.

Comment: First it would be helpful to see which things do not work... you only wrote `it shows an error that I missing some dependency which not included in my pom.xml` but neither the error itself etc. nor your pom file at all...

Comment: @khmarbaise I just complement the log and pom.xml :)

Comment: So `Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline` this is the problem...

Comment: But I ```mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml dependency:go-offline``` completed downloading all the dependency the project needed. Further, JBoss is not in pom.xml file. I wonder where it come from